NestJS - Typeorm - Define an entity column with a query
I want to compute directly in the entities :

the globalRating of an user based on the rating where he's tenant of the associated contract
the globalRating of a property based on the ratings where it's the property associated to the contract

Something like this with queryBuilder
const userGlobalRating = await this.userRepo.createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
    .leftJoin('user.tenantships', 'contract')
    .leftJoin('contract.ratings', 'rating')
    .select('user.id', 'id')
    .addSelect('COALESCE(AVG(rating.stars), 0)', 'rating')
    .groupBy('user.id');

const propertyGlobalRAting = await this.propertyRepo.createQueryBuilder(Property, 'property')
    .leftJoin('property.contracts', 'contract')
    .leftJoin('contract.ratings', 'rating')
    .select('property.id', 'id')
    .addSelect('COALESCE(AVG(rating.stars), 0)', 'rating')
    .groupBy('property.id');

Here the entities :
@Entity()
export class Rating {
  @ManyToOne(() => Contract, c => c.ratings)
  @JoinColumn()
  @Index()
  contract!: Contract;
}

@Entity()
export class Contract {
  @OneToMany(() => Rating, rating => rating.contract)
  ratings!: Rating[];


  @ManyToOne(() => Property, property => property.contracts)
  property!: Property | undefined;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.tenantships)
  tenant?: User | undefined;
}

@Entity()
export class Property{
  @OneToMany(() => Contract, contract => contract.property)
  contracts!: Contract[];

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.properties)
  @JoinColumn()
  @Index()
  owner!: User | undefined;

  globalRating!:number
}

@Entity()
export class User {
  @OneToMany(() => Property, property => property.owner)
  properties: Property[] | undefined;
  @OneToMany(() => Contract, contract => contract.tenant)
  tenantships: Contract[];


  globalRating!: number;

}

So is that possible using postgres ?
Is that possible without injecting the repository and just add raw sql ?

You can create a ViewEntity with calculated values ​​and get everything from there via TypeORM.
